# What's the best hash for utf-8 strings

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, hash

what's the best hash function for utf-8 strings that returns 32bit or 64bit integer, both considering performance and 'minimal collisions'

Comment: I think that depends on the strings you want to hash.

Comment: A very comprehensive answer is given under a [link](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx#fnv) suggested by Christoph. It describes 11 popular hash functions, with source code, pro et contras, general discussion.

Answer (score 3):

XOR version of [djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) algorithm:

```
unsigned long
hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) ^ c; // hash(i - 1) * 33 ^ str[i]

    return hash;
}
```

It's simple, fast and considered one of the best for string hashing.

Comment: I think `hash * 33` is clearer than `(hash<<5)+hash`. Be assured the compiler will find the fastest implementation.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any other, more specific requirements, I'd go with [Fowler/Noll/Vo](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx#fnv) or [Jenkins' one-at-a-time](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx#oat).

Keep in mind that you should always check that your input data won't trigger degenerate cases (ie excessive collisions).

Answer (score 0):

I currently use the one below. It is not fundamentally better than the *33 djb version (or FNV or Jenkins), but it has a somewhat better entropy in the lower bits, which is needed if the table sizes are powers of two.

```
unsigned hash_mem(void *dat, size_t len)
{
unsigned char *str = (unsigned char*) dat;
unsigned val=0;
size_t idx;

for(idx=0; idx < len; idx++ )   {
        val ^= (val >> 2) ^ (val << 5) ^ (val << 13) ^ str[idx] ^ 0x80001801;
        }
return val;
}
```